# Can't pass object to view in nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to configure passport in a node project, i have the login and signup working but I can't pass my account object to my view so that i can say 'Welcome, firstname'

My passport login strategy returns the account and is as follows:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            Account.findOne({'username' : username}, function(err, account){
        if(err)
            return done(err);

        if(!account)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

        if(!account.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

        //console.log('email: ' + account.email);
        return done(null, account);
        });
    }); 
}));
```

My route that uses that uses that strategy is:

```
app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile',
    failureRedirect : '/',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

and the profile route:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var jaccount = JSON.stringify(req.account);
    //console.log('email: ' + jaccount.email);
    res.render('../app/views/profile/index.ejs', {
        account : jaccount
    });
});
```

and the isLoggedIn function:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

The view gives the error:

> > 21|                 <% if (account.email) { %>
> >        22|
> >
> > 23|
> >
> > <%= account.account_type %>
> >
> > 24|
> >
> > <%= account.username %>
> >
> > Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, this is my first node project so apologies for silly mistakes.

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: What view engine are you using?

Comment: You don't need to `stringify` it. Also passport adds the user session to `req.user` not `req.account`.

Comment: Using stringify was because i had seen some post online and decided to try it, meant to take it out before posting. Changing req.account to req.user worked a treat. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's also no need to use `process.nextTick` in your verify callback. Jared only put that in his sample for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the actual object to the view rather than running it through `JSON.stringify()`:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    //var jaccount = JSON.stringify(req.account);
    //console.log('email: ' + jaccount.email);
    res.render('../app/views/profile/index.ejs', {
        account : req.account
    });
});
```